# Typescript definition testing

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm writing a typescript definition for a library. While I can write tests for the library runtime (its javascript output), I'd also like to write repeatable/automated tests for its typedefs, since they tend to get more complicated with the heavier use of generics, inference and sort.

I feel a bit limited on that, I'd like to write tests like: "this assignment should fail" or "this should throw a compiler error". Is there already any existing/established tool regarding that aspect?

Comment: *"this should throw a compiler error"* - won't you find this out at compile time?

Comment: I guess this is applicable, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to write tests like: "this assignment should fail" or "this should throw a compiler error". Is there already any existing/established tool regarding that aspect

No. Normally tests only ensure that *this assignment works* and *this should not throw a compiler error*. That is what the tests do in DefinitelyTyped : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped